# GPS Location won't update

Tags: android, gps

I want to programm a GPS Positioner which is updating the position every 15 seconds. However the method (onLocationChanged) to update isnt called...
It sets only one time the location in the TextView when pressing the button, the time showing is also sometimes minutes before...

When exactly get onLocationChanged called? Forced every 10 seconds (or faster) or only when the location changes?

my code (only the code for GPS, there is also code to check if google play services is activated):

```
/* IMPORT FILES */

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
LocationListener {

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
 * Attributes
 */
private static LocationClient   mLocationClient;
private static boolean          LocEnabled = false;
private static boolean          LocConnected = false;
private static LocationRequest  LocRequest;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
 * Location Update Settings
 */
// Milliseconds per second
private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
// Update frequency in seconds
public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 15;
// Update frequency in milliseconds
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
// The fastest update frequency, in seconds
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 1;
// A fast frequency ceiling in milliseconds
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
 * Local Vars
 */
SharedPreferences Prefs;
Editor Editor;
boolean UpdatesRequested;

//VIEW Elements
static Button       btn_refresh_loc;
static TextView     txt_position;
static View rootView;

//Position elements
static Position     myPosition = new Position("Meine Position");
static Location     lastLocation;


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
 * METHODS TO CHECK FOR GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES */

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    //check for G-Play Services
    if(servicesConnected())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Google Play Services available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("G Play Services", "Google Play Services available");
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Google Play Services not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("G Play Services", "Google Play Services NOT AVAILABLE");

        finish();
    }

    //check for Location Service activated
    if(checkLocEnabled())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Service enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("LOC", "Location Service enabled");   

        LocEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Service disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("LOC", "Location Service DISABLED");

        showGPSsettings();
    }

    // Open the shared preferences
    Prefs = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Get a SharedPreferences editor
    Editor = Prefs.edit();


    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this,this,this);
    UpdatesRequested = true;    //start loc client without updates

    //set loc update parameter
    LocRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    LocRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    LocRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        //View inits
        btn_refresh_loc = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh_loc);
        txt_position = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_location);

        //ClickListeners
        btn_refresh_loc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.i("BTN","Get Location");

                if(!LocEnabled)
                {
                    // Reconnect the client.
                    mLocationClient.disconnect();
                    mLocationClient.connect();
                }

                if(LocConnected)
                {
                    lastLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
                    myPosition.setPos(lastLocation);

                    String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (lastLocation.getTime()));
                    // Report to the UI that the location was updated   
                    txt_position.setText("Lat: " + myPosition.getLat() + " Lng: " + myPosition.getLng() + "\n" + date);
                    Log.i("LOC","Lat: " + myPosition.getLat() + " Lng: " + myPosition.getLng() + "\n" + date);
                }
            }
        });



        return rootView;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Connect the client.
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // Save the current setting for updates
    Editor.putBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", UpdatesRequested);
    Editor.commit();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    /*
     * Get any previous setting for location updates
     * Gets "false" if an error occurs
     */
    if (Prefs.contains("KEY_UPDATES_ON")) {
        UpdatesRequested =
                Prefs.getBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", false);

    // Otherwise, turn off location updates
    } else {
        Editor.putBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", false);
        Editor.commit();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    /*if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        removeLocationUpdates(this);
    }*/

    // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    LocConnected = false;
    super.onStop();
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
 * Location Services
 */

/*
 * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
 * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
 * request the current location or start periodic updates
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    // Display the connection status
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    LocConnected = true;
    if (UpdatesRequested) {
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(LocRequest, this);
    }

}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
 * location client drops because of an error.
 */
@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // Display the connection status
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    LocConnected = false;
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
 * Location Services fails.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
     * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
     * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
     * error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                    this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
             * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
             * PendingIntent
             */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        /*
         * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
         * user with the error.
         */
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: Location Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Location", "Connection failed - " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
    LocConnected = false;
}


/*
 * Define the callback method that receives location updates(non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location)
 */
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (location.getTime()));
    // Report to the UI that the location was updated   
    txt_position.setText("# Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " Lng: " + location.getLongitude() + "\n" + date);
    Log.i("LOC","# Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " Lng: " + location.getLongitude() + "\n" + date);
}

}
```

The code is partially copied from the Google Developer Training sites

Comment: follow this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: I don't know what the error was, but now it works. Thank you!